# C++ Copy a matrix to another inside a class using reference

Tags: c++, class, matrix, ref

This function is supposed to copy a matrix to another but will not work for me. I have shown the privates in the class. This is inside a class function and I just need the copy statement. Have tried for so long and am completely stuck. Please help!

```
private:

double ** matrixM;   // points to an array of double-pointers on the heap
double* sum_rowsM;   // points to an array of doubles on the heap
double* sum_colsM;   // points to an array of doubles on the heap
int rowsM;           // number of rows of matrix
int colsM;           // number of columns of matrix

void Matrix::copy(const Matrix& source)
{
    // THIS FUNCITON IS DEFECTIVE AND DOSEN'T PROPERLY MAKE THE COPY OF SOURCE
    if(source.matrixM == NULL){
        matrixM = NULL;
        sum_rowsM = NULL;
        sum_colsM = NULL;
        rowsM = 0;
        colsM = 0;
        return;
    }
    
    rowsM = source.rowsM;
    colsM = source.colsM;
    
    sum_rowsM = new double[rowsM];
    assert(sum_rowsM != NULL);
    
    
    sum_colsM = new double[colsM];
    assert(sum_colsM != NULL);
    
    matrixM = new double*[rowsM];
    assert(matrixM !=NULL);
    for(int i =0; i < rowsM; i++){
        matrixM[i] = new double[colsM];
        assert(matrixM[i] != NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: All your function does is allocate a bunch of uninitialized memory. If you want to copy values into that memory, you need to actually copy values into that memory.

Comment: First of all: what is `Matrix` type declared in the paramters of `void Matrix::copy`? Why use so many `double` arrays if you already have a matrix type? Further you allocate a lot of memory but never initialize it to any values

Comment: And you should define a copy constructor or copy assignment operator, not a function named `copy`.